# Why producer processes doesn't stop producing even if the buffer is full?

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory, producer-consumer

I wrote a producer-consumer synchronization code with m producer processes and n consumer processes. I am having trouble in debugging it. The buffer is shared between all consumer and producer processes while in variable is shared between all producer processes. Each product is represented by a product id.

There are 3 semaphores:

i) Full semaphore is to stop consumer processes to access buffer if Full semaphore value is 0.

ii) Empty semaphore is to stop producer processes to access buffer if Empty semaphore value is 0.

iii) Mutex semaphore is for mutual exclusion.

Shared.h

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define buffer_size 5
#define empty_id 0
#define full_id 1
#define mutex_id 2
#define no_sem 3

struct sembuf signall = {0 , 1, 0};
struct sembuf wait = {0, -1, 0};

#define W(s) semop(s, &wait, 1);
#define S(s) semop(s, &signall, 1);

int shmid,shmid1,shmid2;
int *buffer;

union semun
{
                int val;
                struct semid_ds *buf;
                unsigned short  *array;
                struct seminfo  *__buf;

}setvalarg[3];

int *create_shared_mem_buffer()
{
        int *shmaddr;
        key_t key = 85;

        shmid = shmget(key, buffer_size, IPC_CREAT|0660);

        shmaddr= (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

        return shmaddr;
}

int create_semaphore_set()
{
        key_t key=65;

        int semid= semget(key, no_sem, IPC_CREAT|0600);

        setvalarg[0].val=buffer_size;
        semctl(semid, empty_id, SETVAL, setvalarg[0]);

        setvalarg[1].val=0;
        semctl(semid, full_id, SETVAL, setvalarg[1]);

        setvalarg[2].val=1;
        semctl(semid, mutex_id, SETVAL, setvalarg[2]);

        return semid;
}
```

Producer.c

```
#include "shared.h"

void insert_product(int item, int *in, int *buffer)
{
        *in=(*in+1)%buffer_size;
        buffer[*in]=item;
        printf("Producer produces item with id %d stored in posn %d  \n",item,*in);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i, pid, item;
        int *in, *in1;
        buffer = create_shared_mem_buffer();
        int semid= create_semaphore_set();


        shmid2=  shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT | 0777);
        in=(int *)shmat(shmid2, NULL, 0);
        *in=-1;

        int n=5;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                pid=fork();
                if(pid==0)
                {
                        srand(getpid());
                        in1=(int *)shmat(shmid2, NULL, 0);
                        while(1)
                        {
                                item=rand();
                                wait.sem_num=0;
                                W(semid);
                                wait.sem_num=2;
                                W(semid);
                                insert_product(item, in1, buffer);
                                signall.sem_num=2;
                                S(semid);
                                signall.sem_num=1;
                                S(semid);
                        }
                }
         }
        return(0);
}
```

The problem is that the producer processes after producing 5(buffer_size) products should wait for the consumer process to consume the products and then fill the buffer again.

The output is as:(without consumer processes being executed)

```
Producer produces item with id 1170454448 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item with id 1942442557 stored in posn 1  
Producer produces item with id 1638563672 stored in posn 2  
Producer produces item with id 1338160125 stored in posn 3  
Producer produces item with id 2111694856 stored in posn 4  
Producer produces item with id 1525954635 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item with id 1346192014 stored in posn 1  
Producer produces item with id 1158563802 stored in posn 2  
Producer produces item with id 973413556 stored in posn 3  
Producer produces item with id 787723313 stored in posn 4
```

What/where is the problem? How to debug it?

If further information required drop a comment below.

Comment: `shmaddr= (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);` - You do not need the cast

Comment: shmat returns `void *` pointer so I explicitly type casted it to `int *` . Anyways it wasn't required. I don't think this modification will help me.

Comment: Before the `return(0)` put in an infinite loop. Then count the number of processes that are created

Comment: Where are you storing in the shared memory the number of items that are in the buffer?

Comment: @EdHeal I didn't create any such variable to count the number of items at any instant in the buffer. The value of empty semaphore will determine whether there are any empty places available, that's why I `wait()` the empty semaphore. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @EdHeal When I see the process id's of the producer's that produced items, I see that a process(say, 0) inserts item in posn 0, 1 in posn 1..........upto process 4 in posn 4 and again the same sequence is repeated i.e., now process 0 inserts a new item in posn 0.  The number of process created is 5(=value of n) only.

Comment: Are you sure that only 5 processes are created?

Comment: Yes, I am printing the pid's in the critical section(insert_product function).

Comment: Please do the about - I think you find there are a lot more processes than you think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207922/discussion-between-hamsa-and-ed-heal).